# Using $_GET data as a variable

Tags: php, minecraft

I've been trying to check the status of my Minecraft servers. I have the script working, however, I'd like to use `$_GET[""];` to allow me to have an API of some sorts.

My code with `$_GET[""];` looks like this:

```
$Connection = $_GET["connection"];
require_once('MinecraftServerStatus.class.php');
$Server = new MinecraftServerStatus('$Connection');
```

It also relies on another file with this code:

```
class MinecraftServerStatus {
    //...
    public function __construct($Host, $Port = 25565, $Timeout = 1) {
        //...
    }
 }
```

However, when entering the IP of the server `link/to/page.php?connection=IP)` it doesn't give any of the information output (only the manually entered text), but when manually entering an IP and removing the `$_GET[""]` code that will work.

I would be very greatful if someone knows how I can use `$_GET[""];` with this code to make it work or if its impossible (at least then I can stop trying).

Comment: Try removing these single quotes first $Server = new MinecraftServerStatus('$Connection');

Comment: @KA_lin you should make that an answer, it's the solution.

Comment: @KA_lin thank you very much! I cannot believe it was that simple. Thank you very much. Please post it as an answer and I will set it as the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the single quotes from your third line of code because when putting variables in single quotes they won`t be interpreted.

Just use:

```
$Server = new MinecraftServerStatus($Connection);
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes around $Connection in this line:

```
$Server = new MinecraftServerStatus('$Connection');
```

becomes:

```
$Server = new MinecraftServerStatus($Connection);
```

In your code, you are literally passing the string `'$Connection'` to the `MinecraftServerStatus` constructor instead of the contents of the variable `$Connection`.

Note, you can use **double** quotes to expand variables inside strings, but that's usually better suited for when you have a longer string e.g. `echo "Hello $name, how are you?"`.

(And even in that case I like to use print_r() instead, e.g. `print_r('Hello %s, how are you?', $name);`)

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before I can set as answer, thanks for giving a bit of background on it too! :)